# MeteorJS Tutorial & detailed explanation

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I just finished the JS course on codecademy and started learning meteorJS for Angular 2 now for building my first real application. I started with the simple-todos tutorial but noticed that the tutorial isn't for real noob beginners but instead for intermediate programmers. I do not understand what the single lines of code do

for example:

```
angular.module('simple-todos', [
    angularMeteor
]);
```

This is one of the many examples which are not clearly explained in the tutorial.

Do you know a source where I could learn all this noob stuff before I continue with Meteor?

Thank you!

Comment: this has nothing to with meteor. please check https://angularjs.org/ to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think the official Meteor tutorials do a really good job of explaining all the meteor specific stuff that it covers. One thing you could do is also pull up the [Meteor API](https://docs.meteor.com/api/) and read the details about a specific function it asks you to use as you progress. This will certainly provide some more meat to the tutorial.

The piece of code that you provided in your question is actually Angular specific code.  Angular itself has a somewhat steep learning curve so by doing that tutorial, you are taking quite a big step by trying to learn Angular and Meteor at the same time.

Instead, I highly recommend you follow the [Meteor Blaze tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app). It provides much more detail and it covers ONLY meteor specific stuff. Once you finish that then read the [Meteor guide](https://guide.meteor.com) and if you have the funds, buy the [Discover Meteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com) book and follow that tutorial.  This approach is exactly how I learned Meteor and it was very successful for me.

Be sure to just read along in the [Meteor API](https://docs.meteor.com/api/) and [Blaze API](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html) as you progress thru any tutorial and you will be well on your way (and then later you can jump into learning Angular or React with Meteor if it suites your fancy)! Honestly, I have had a lot of success with Blaze and use it for Meteor apps 99% of the time.

Comment: Hi Jordan, thank you so much for your advice! That's what i'll do! I totally lost myself checking meteor stuff and at same time angular specific stuff... its too much for first framework. at least for me.

Comment: @cytzix glad I could help! Since you are new to stackoverflow, let me remind you to accept the answer and/or upvote the answer if it helped you so that others who stumble upon your question in the future (because they have the same question) will see that the answer helped you and follow the same advice.

Comment: Thanks @jordanwillis! I want to add some other resources: [the Meteor forums](https://forums.meteor.com/) and [Meteor's official Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC3fBiJrFFMhKlsWM46AsAYw). These are very helpful if you want to ask questions / update what's going on with Meteor.